# How match sub-hostname is from main-hostname through regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, dns

like this. a host name match "*".

```
// ----------------------
*.example.com
    www.example.com  -> pass
    img.example.com  -> pass
    www.example2.com -> fail
```

or

```
// ----------------------
www.example.com
    www.example.com -> pass
    img.example.com -> fail
```

for all top domain "com" match.

```
enter code here
// -----------------------
*.com
    www.a.com -> pass
    www.b.com -> pass
    www.c.org -> fail
```

or simple for all domain.

```
//------------------------
*
    www.a.com -> pass
    img.b.com -> pass
    c.org     -> pass
```

Comment: Maybe show us your try on a regex, and others may more easily help where it needs correction or could use optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make all your matches into regexps by:

- replacing `*` with `.*`
- replacing `.` with `\.` (in java String it needs to be `\\.`)

And then you can use following code to match the strings to be tested:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\.example\\.com");
Matcher m = p.matcher("www.example.com");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Your matching strings:

- `*.example.com` -> `.*\.example\.com`
- `www.example.com` -> `www\.example\.com`
- `*.com` -> `.*\.com`
- `*` -> `.*`

Comment: it's amazing! this method work for me. Thank you! `"*.example.com".replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*")`